# How to hyperlink an image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, parallax

I would like to set hyperlink on an image with this JSON: `{url: 'img/enf.png', x: 1200, y: 530, offset: -0.1}` in a parallax effect, so if you click on this image, you go to "news.html".

Code I currently have:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body{
    margin:0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #pozadi{
    background-image: url(img/pozadi.png);
    overflow: hidden;

    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    min-height: 500px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pozadi">
      <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
  <script src="tweenmax.js"></script>
  <script src="snapsvg.js"></script>
  <script>

  if (screen.width > 1200){
  var assets = [
    {url: 'img/vybuch.png', x: 0, y: 60, offset: -0.25},
    {url: 'img/psi.png', x: 200, y: 80, offset: -0.2},
    {url: 'img/kour.png', x: 120, y: 280, offset: -0.15},
    {url: 'img/enf.png', x: 1200, y: 530, offset: -0.1},
    {url: 'img/csf.png', x: -40, y: 530, offset: -0.1},
    {url: 'img/nadpis.png', x: 350, y: 530, offset: 0.01},
    {url: 'img/sbt.png', x: 610, y: 665, offset: 0.01},
  ],
  layers = [],

      w = screen.width,
      h = screen.height,
      loaded = 0,
      container = document.getElementById('container'),
      s = new Snap(w, h);

  container.appendChild(s.node);

  g = s.g();
  c = s.g();
  c.attr({transform: 'scale(1)'});
  g.append(c);

  for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = assets[i].url;
    img.onload = handle_load;

    /*Start my code*/
    if (i==3) { //3 is your 'img/enf.png', or check the string in img.src 
        img.onclick = function(e){
            window.location.href = 'www.debil.cz';
        }
    }
    /*End my code*/

    var _img = s.image(assets[i].url, assets[i].x, assets[i].y);
    c.append(_img);
    layers.push(_img);
  }


  function handle_load(e) {
    loaded += 1;

    if (loaded == assets.length) {
      handle_loaded();
    }
  }

  function handle_loaded() {

    container.addEventListener('mousemove', handle_mousemove);
    container.addEventListener('mouseout', handle_mouseout);
    container.addEventListener('mouseover', handle_mouseover);
  }

  function handle_mousemove(e) {
    var dx = e.offsetX - (w / 2);
    var dy = e.offsetY - (h / 2);

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i += 1) {
      var l = layers[i];
      var _x = dx * assets[i].offset;
      var _y = dy * assets[i].offset;
      TweenMax.to(l.node, 0.1, {x: _x, y: _y});
    }
  }

  function handle_mouseout(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i += 1) {
      var l = layers[i];
      TweenMax.to(l.node, 0.2, {x: 0, y: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut});
    }

    TweenMax.to(s.node, 0.2, {scale: 0.9, rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut});
    TweenMax.to(c.node, 1, {rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0});
  }

  function handle_mouseover(e) {
    TweenMax.to(s.node, 0.2, {scale: 1, ease: Back.easeOut});
  }

  function angleToPoints(angle) {
    var segment = Math.floor(angle / Math.PI * 2) + 2;
    var diagonal =  (1/2 * segment + 1/4) * Math.PI;
    var op = Math.cos(Math.abs(diagonal - angle)) * Math.sqrt(2);
    var x = op * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = op * Math.sin(angle);

    return {
      x1: x < 0 ? 1 : 0,
      y1: y < 0 ? 1 : 0,
      x2: x >= 0 ? x : x + 1,
      y2: y >= 0 ? y : y + 1
    };
  }
}else if (screen.width > 600){
  var assets = [
    {url: 'img/vybuch_tablet.png', x: -450, y: 80, offset: -0.25},
    {url: 'img/psi_tablet.png', x: -280, y: 140, offset: -0.2},
    {url: 'img/kour_tablet.png', x: -220, y: 350, offset: -0.15},
    {url: 'img/enf_tablet.png', x: 470, y: 830, offset: -0.1},
    {url: 'img/csf_tablet.png', x: 85, y: 830, offset: -0.1},
    {url: 'img/nadpis_tablet.png', x: 5, y: 610, offset: 0.01},
    {url: 'img/sbt_tablet.png', x: 150, y: 740, offset: 0.01},
  ],
  layers = [],

      w = screen.width,
      h = screen.height,
      loaded = 0,
      container = document.getElementById('container'),
      s = new Snap(w, h);

  container.appendChild(s.node);

  g = s.g();
  c = s.g();
  c.attr({transform: 'scale(1)'});
  g.append(c);

  for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = assets[i].url;
    img.onload = handle_load;

    var _img = s.image(assets[i].url, assets[i].x, assets[i].y);
    c.append(_img);
    layers.push(_img);
  }


  function handle_load(e) {
    loaded += 1;

    if (loaded == assets.length) {
      handle_loaded();
    }
  }

  function handle_loaded() {

    container.addEventListener('mousemove', handle_mousemove);
    container.addEventListener('mouseout', handle_mouseout);
    container.addEventListener('mouseover', handle_mouseover);
  }

  function handle_mousemove(e) {
    var dx = e.offsetX - (w / 2);
    var dy = e.offsetY - (h / 2);

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i += 1) {
      var l = layers[i];
      var _x = dx * assets[i].offset;
      var _y = dy * assets[i].offset;
      TweenMax.to(l.node, 0.1, {x: _x, y: _y});
    }
  }

  function handle_mouseout(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i += 1) {
      var l = layers[i];
      TweenMax.to(l.node, 0.2, {x: 0, y: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut});
    }

    TweenMax.to(s.node, 0.2, {scale: 0.9, rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut});
    TweenMax.to(c.node, 1, {rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0});
  }

  function handle_mouseover(e) {
    TweenMax.to(s.node, 0.2, {scale: 1, ease: Back.easeOut});
  }

  function angleToPoints(angle) {
    var segment = Math.floor(angle / Math.PI * 2) + 2;
    var diagonal =  (1/2 * segment + 1/4) * Math.PI;
    var op = Math.cos(Math.abs(diagonal - angle)) * Math.sqrt(2);
    var x = op * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = op * Math.sin(angle);

    return {
      x1: x < 0 ? 1 : 0,
      y1: y < 0 ? 1 : 0,
      x2: x >= 0 ? x : x + 1,
      y2: y >= 0 ? y : y + 1
    };
  }
}else{
  var assets = [
    {url: 'img/vybuch_phone.png', x: 0, y: 0, offset: -0.25},
    {url: 'img/psi_phone.png', x: -400, y: 0, offset: -0.2},
    {url: 'img/kour_phone.png', x: -300, y: 100, offset: -0.15},
    {url: 'img/enf_phone.png', x: 200, y: 540, offset: -0.1},
    {url: 'img/csf_phone.png', x: 20, y: 540, offset: -0.1},
    {url: 'img/nadpis_phone.png', x: 30, y: 430, offset: 0.01},
    {url: 'img/sbt_phone.png', x: 65, y: 495, offset: 0.01},
  ],
  layers = [],

      w = screen.width,
      h = screen.height,
      loaded = 0,
      container = document.getElementById('container'),
      s = new Snap(w, h);

  container.appendChild(s.node);

  g = s.g();
  c = s.g();
  c.attr({transform: 'scale(1)'});
  g.append(c);

  for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = assets[i].url;
    img.onload = handle_load;

    var _img = s.image(assets[i].url, assets[i].x, assets[i].y);
    c.append(_img);
    layers.push(_img);
  }


  function handle_load(e) {
    loaded += 1;

    if (loaded == assets.length) {
      handle_loaded();
    }
  }

  function handle_loaded() {

    container.addEventListener('mousemove', handle_mousemove);
    container.addEventListener('mouseout', handle_mouseout);
    container.addEventListener('mouseover', handle_mouseover);
  }

  function handle_mousemove(e) {
    var dx = e.offsetX - (w / 2);
    var dy = e.offsetY - (h / 2);

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i += 1) {
      var l = layers[i];
      var _x = dx * assets[i].offset;
      var _y = dy * assets[i].offset;
      TweenMax.to(l.node, 0.1, {x: _x, y: _y});
    }
  }

  function handle_mouseout(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i += 1) {
      var l = layers[i];
      TweenMax.to(l.node, 0.2, {x: 0, y: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut});
    }

    TweenMax.to(s.node, 0.2, {scale: 0.9, rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0, ease: Quad.easeOut});
    TweenMax.to(c.node, 1, {rotationY: 0, rotationX: 0});
  }

  function handle_mouseover(e) {
    TweenMax.to(s.node, 0.2, {scale: 1, ease: Back.easeOut});
  }

  function angleToPoints(angle) {
    var segment = Math.floor(angle / Math.PI * 2) + 2;
    var diagonal =  (1/2 * segment + 1/4) * Math.PI;
    var op = Math.cos(Math.abs(diagonal - angle)) * Math.sqrt(2);
    var x = op * Math.cos(angle);
    var y = op * Math.sin(angle);

    return {
      x1: x < 0 ? 1 : 0,
      y1: y < 0 ? 1 : 0,
      x2: x >= 0 ? x : x + 1,
      y2: y >= 0 ? y : y + 1
    };
  }
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to do it with an `a` tag using href attribute in my html, but it totally breaks the parallax effect.

I am not the expert in javascript, I just changed the code I found and it works perfectly, but in my project, I definitelly need to set a link on the image. Do you have any idea how to do it please?

Comment: Can you give us a clearer and more concise example to work with? We don't have access to your assets or the rest of your code structure. Based on this question revolving around your use of parallax, it would be helpful to get a better handle on what we're working with

Comment: Sure, the body is composed of two divs:(<div id="pozadi"><div id="container"></div></div>) - first one is a background, the second one is for parallax on mouseover from this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3RO5BtMiolo). In assets I just have few images and one of them is supposed to take you to news.html.

Comment: You should provide real code that runs rather then explain it with a vague code. Recommend editing the post and adding your HTML code snippet with the parallax problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (into the first for):

```
 for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = assets[i].url;
    img.onload = handle_load;

    /*Start my code*/
    if (i==3) { //3 is your 'img/enf.png', or check the string in img.src 
        img.onclick = function(e){
            window.location.href = 'the link of your news.html';
        }
    }
    /*End my code*/

    var _img = s.image(assets[i].url, assets[i].x, assets[i].y);
    c.append(_img);
    layers.push(_img);

  }
```

---

### **EDIT**

You are right, we wrong.

**First of all, what your code generate is an SVG, and the SNAP library click event is this: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.click**

For this reason, the code above must be modified in this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = assets[i].url;
    img.onload = handle_load;

    var _img = s.image(assets[i].url, assets[i].x, assets[i].y);

    /*Start my code*/
    if (i==3) {
        _img.click(function(){
            //window.location.href = 'www.debil.cz';
            alert('yeah');
        });
    }
    /*End my code*/


    c.append(_img);
    layers.push(_img);
}
```

**BUT**

**You must remember that:** *the parallax effect work on layers, and the click event can't fired if an "invisible" element is below (as a blank region of a PNG).*

Here a working example but with click on the item in the foreground !!
https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/hachn1sL/3/

Here another working example with click on the third element, and the event fired only on very top (because the first is above).
https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/hachn1sL/4/

Your assets array has as the last item inserted the highest element.

Comment: It doesn´t work in my project, don´t realy know why.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested, but based on the information you provided this may help.

```
  for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = assets[i].url;
    img.onload = handle_load;

    //use an if statement to grab correct asset
    //change page on click
    if (img.src === "img/vybuch.png") {
      img.onclick = function(e) {
        document.location = "http://www.google.com/";
      }
    }

    var _img = s.image(assets[i].url, assets[i].x, assets[i].y);
    c.append(_img);
    layers.push(_img);
  }
```

**Example:**

```js
var assets = [
{url: 'http://www.livefirelabs.com/images/learn-unix-demo-course.jpg', x: 0, y: 60, offset: -0.25},
]

for (var i = 0; i < assets.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = assets[i].url;
        img.onload = handle_load;

        //use an if statement to grab correct asset
        //change page on click
        if (img.src === "http://www.livefirelabs.com/images/learn-unix-demo-course.jpg") {
          img.onclick = function(e) {
            document.location = "https://jsfiddle.net/";
          }
        }
        
       
        document.body.appendChild(img);
      }

function handle_load() {
//do nothing
}
```

Comment: Well, I can see it should work, but it doesn´t in my project and I do not really know why.

Comment: @DominikZáliš I don't mean any disrespect, but in this case it sounds like it would be best to do a bit more research into what your code is actually doing. It seems like you're taking a project and trying to warp it to your needs, and by all means that's a perfectly good way to learn, but if you can't insert this demo into what you have it signals to me that you are not entirely positive what's happening in the code. We've all been there, but the only thing that's going to cure it is a bit more time in the trenches. Don't worry, you'll get it, but it does take time.

Comment: I just need to complete this javascript parallax and I hoped it would be easy for you guys to help me but now I can see it is not. Huh, I will have to study the javascript a bit. Thank you for your time. :-)